# Find basis from matrix representation of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

If I have a vector space like $U=\{f\in End(\mathbb{R}^3)$ such that $... \}$ (a certain condition) and I know that the matrix representation of $f$ (with respect to two basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$) is $$\begin{pmatrix}
a & c & p \\
b & d &  q\\
0 & 0 & r \end{pmatrix}$$ with $a,b,c,p,q,r$ free variables.

Then can I find a basis of $U$?

Comment: $f$ occurs twice in different roles.

Comment: I have edited .

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
a & c & p \\
b & d &  q\\
0 & 0 & r \end{pmatrix}= a\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}+b\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 &  0\\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}+c\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}+\cdots$$